# ILE RPG: Using QMHSNDPM, call stack entry not found

Tags: rpgle

I am attempting to wade into the pool of MVC for RPG ILE.  So I have two modules VIEW, and MODEL, that are bound to my main program CNTRL.  I validate information entered in my VIEW module with calls to the MODEL module, and then pass back to the View any errors.  When I try to use the QHNSNDPM api, I see the error in the job log, followed by CALL STACK ENTRY NOT FOUND.  I tried to find theVIEW module on the call stack, and it is not there.  Not being super strong in DDS and the ILE, I am not sure how/what to do about this error.  Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The DCL-F DISPLAY WORKSTN; is in the VIEW module.

And now for a little code from the VIEW Module....

```
   dcl-pr SendMsg Extpgm('QMHSNDPM');
     MsgID char(7) const;
     MsgF  char(20) const;
     MsgData char(30) const;
     MsgDataLen  int(10) const;
     MsgType char(10) const;
     CallStackEnt char(10) const;
     CallStackCtr int(10) const;
     MsgKey char(4) const;
     Error  like(ErrorDS);

   end-pr;
  *******************************************************************

   dcl-proc VIEW_SetError EXPORT;
     dcl-pi *n;
        Msg int(3);
        MSGQ char(10);
     end-pi ;
     // The MSGQ parameter is from the PSDS *PROC
     // I tried having this defined in the view where the DDS file
     // is defined, and I have tried with it defined in the main CNTRL program

     Dcl-s MsgTxt char(30);


     if Msg=1;
        MsgTxt='Invalid Facility';
        AT1FAC=setAttr(*omit:'RI');
     elseif Msg=2;
         MsgTxt='Status must be O, C, or A!';
         AT1STAT=setAttr(*omit:'RI');
     elseif Msg=3;
         MsgTxt='Invalid Order Number';
         AT1ITEM=setAttr(*omit:'RI');
     elseif Msg=4;
         MsgTxt='Invalid Vendor Number';
         AT1VEND=setAttr(*omit:'RI');
     elseif Msg=5;
         MsgTxt='Invalid Pallet Number';
         AT1PLT=setAttr(*omit:'RI');
     endif;


      callp  SendMsg (*blanks: *blanks :
             MsgTxt : %size(MsgTxt):
            '*INFO': '*':
              0: *blanks: ErrorDS);
      // I have tried setting the CallStackEnt to * and C 
      // And the CallStackCtr to 0,1,2
     write msgctl;

   end-proc ;
```

and the DDS for DISPLAY....

```
     A                                      DSPSIZ(24 80 *DS3)
 A                                      CHGINPDFT(UL FE)
 A                                      PRINT
 A                                      HELP
 A                                      ALTHELP(CA01)
 A*                                     ALTPAGEUP(CF07)
 A*                                     ALTPAGEDWN(CF08)
 A                                      CF03(03)
 A                                      CF04(04)
 A                                      CF06(06)
 A                                      CF12(12)
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
  * Screen 1 - Filter Criteria
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
 A          R SCREEN1

 A                                      OVERLAY
 A                                      BLINK
 A                                      RTNCSRLOC(&REC1 &FLD1)
 A                                      CSRLOC(XROW1 XCOL1)
 A            XROW1          3S 0H
 A            XCOL1          3S 0H
 A            REC1          10A  H
 A            FLD1          10A  H
 A                                  1  2'SCN200-01'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
 A            COMPANY       40A  O  1 20DSPATR(HI)
 A            WSID          10A  O  1 62
 A                                  1 73DATE
 A                                      EDTCDE(Y)
 A                                  2  2SYSNAME
 A                                  2 23'Pallet Maintenance'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
 A                                  2 62USER
 A                                  2 73TIME
 A                                  5  4'Enter Facility to Search'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
 A                                  7  7'Facility:'
 A            DFAC1          2   B  7 21
 A                                      DSPATR(&AT1FAC)
 A            AT1FAC         1A  P
 A                                  7 24'+'
 A                                  8  2'Pallet Status:'
 A            DSTAT          1   B  8 21
 A                                      DSPATR(&AT1STAT)
 A            AT1STAT        1A  P
 A                                  8 24'(O=Open, C=Closed, or A=All)'
 A                                 10  4'Search by Item and/or Vendor:'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
 A                                 11 11'Item:'
 A            DITM1         15A  B 11 21
 A                                      DSPATR(&AT1ITEM)
 A            AT1ITEM        1A  P
 A                                 11 37'+  (Blank=All)'
 A                                 12  9'Vendor:'
 A            DVND1          5S 0B 12 21
 A                                      DSPATR(&AT1VEND)
 A            AT1VEND        1A  P
 A                                 12 28'+           (Blank=All)'
 A                                 15  7'Or By Pallet ID:'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
 A                                 16  9'Pallet:'
 A            DPLT1         11A  B 16 21
 A                                      DSPATR(&AT1PLT)
 A            AT1PLT         1A  P
 A                                 18  4'IF ALL SEARCH FIELDS LEFT BLANK, +
 A                                       ALL FACILITY RECORDS'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
 A                                 19  6 'DISPLAYED IN PALLET ID ORDER.'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
 A                                 23  2'F3=Exit'
 A                                      COLOR(BLU)
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
  * Message Subfile
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
 A          R MSGRCD                    TEXT('MSG SFL RECORD')
 A                                      SFL SFLMSGRCD(24)
 A            MSGKEY                    SFLMSGKEY
 A            PGMSGQ                    SFLPGMQ
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
  * Message Subfile Control
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
 A          R MSGCTL                    TEXT('MSG SFL CONTROL')
 A                                      OVERLAY SFLCTL(MSGRCD) SFLSIZ(10)
 A                                      SFLPAG(1) SFLDSPCTL SFLDSP SFLINZ
 A N98                                  SFLEND
 A            PGMSGQ                    SFLPGMQ
```

Here is the CL that starts the process....its pretty basic, but we use a lot of overrides in our legacy code, so I thought it would help to start with a CL...

```
         PGM

         DCL        VAR(&COMPANY) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(40) VALUE('BROWNFOX')
         CALL       PGM(CNTRL) PARM(&Company)
         ENDPGM
```

By the way, the company bit is a relic to my testing.  I have added the Company retrieval from the service program.

And the CNTRL RPGLE...

```
       ctl-opt dftactgrp(*no) BNDDIR('MVC');
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
  * Mainline processing
  *------------------------------------------------------------------*
   /define MODEL_PalletMaintenance
   /copy TEMPLATE/QCPYSRC,MODEL
   /undefine MODEL_PalletMaintenance
    /define VIEW_GetParms
   /copy TEMPLATE/QCPYSRC,VIEW
   /undefine VIEW_GetParms

   dcl-ds *N PSDS;
     PGMSGQ           *PROC;
     WSID CHAR(10) Pos(244);
     USER CHAR(10) Pos(254);
   end-ds;

   //dcl-s Exit ind;
   //dcl-s ErrorField char(30);
   dcl-s ErrorText char(30);
   dcl-s ErrorID   int(3);
   //dcl-ds Screen1DS likeDS(Screen1);
   dcl-s CurrentStep int(5);
   dcl-c StepExit 0;
   dcl-c StepPrep 1;
   dcl-c StepShowScreen1 2;
   dcl-c StepValidateScreen1 3;
   //dcl-c StepShowScreen2 0;


   dcl-pr cntrl EXTPGM  ;
   END-PR;
   //dcl-PROC cntrl;
    dcl-pi *n;
    END-PI;



   CurrentStep=StepPrep;

   DoU CurrentStep=StepExit;

     select;
       When CurrentStep=StepPrep;
         VIEW_Prep(Screen1DS);
         MODEL_Prep(Screen1DS);
         CurrentStep=StepShowScreen1;
       When CurrentStep=StepShowScreen1;
         if (VIEW_GetParms(Screen1DS));
           CurrentStep=StepValidateScreen1;
         else;
           CurrentStep=StepExit;
         ENDIF;
       When CurrentStep=StepValidateScreen1;
         ErrorID=MODEL_ValidateScreen1(Screen1DS);
         if (ErrorID<>0);
           VIEW_SetError(ErrorID:PGMSGQ);
           CurrentStep=StepShowScreen1;
         else;
           CurrentStep=StepExit;
         ENDIF;
       ENDSL;
   enddo;
   *INLR=*on;
   Return;
```

And I guess if I've taken it this far, I might as well throw in the copy members

MODEL Copy

```
       /if defined(MODEL_PalletMaintenance)

   dcl-ds Screen1DS qualified;
     Company  char(40);
     Facility char(2);
     Status char(1);
     Item char(35);
     Vendor zoned(5:0);
     Pallet char(11);
   END-DS;


   DCL-PR MODEL_Prep;
     *n likeds(Screen1DS);
   END-PR;
   DCL-PR MODEL_ValidateScreen1 int(3);
     *n likeds(Screen1DS);
   END-PR;
   /endif
```

And View....

```
  /if defined(VIEW_GetParms)

   dcl-ds VScreen1DS qualified;
     Company  char(40);
     Facility char(2);
     Status char(1);
     Item char(35);
     Vendor zoned(5:0);
     Pallet char(11);
   END-DS;

    DCL-PR VIEW_Prep;
     *n likeds(VScreen1DS);
   END-PR;

   DCL-PR VIEW_GetParms Ind;
     *n likeds(VScreen1DS);
   END-PR;

   DCL-PR screen1ResetIndicators;
   END-PR;

   DCL-PR ClearScreen1;
   END-PR;

   DCL-PR VIEW_SetError;
     *n int(3);
     *n char(10);
   END-PR;

   /endif
```

Comment: Where's the Program Entry Procedure?  Note that it's not usually worthwhile to separate view & controller in a 5250 application.  Model should part of a service program.

Comment: Ok. So the long and short of it is this.....I am just trying to take a simple(r) program that we have and convert it into atemplate type scenario, hitting as many learning opportunities as I can.  To that end, I have a CL INITIAL, that calls my main program CNTRL which runs between the MODEL and the VIEW modules.  The MODEL module in turn reaches out to SERVICE which is where I put any code that I felt would be useful from multiple programs.  The service program is compiled as a service program, and the VIEW and MODEL modules are compiled as modules.  The CNTRL is compiled as a bound RPGLE.

Comment: I will post the CL and CNTRL into the original question, I just didn't want to over bore anyone.

Comment: Model should be Data model and business rules. I would expect it to be implemented entirely in service programs. Everything related to displaying data to the user, and receiving input should be in the view, and the controller should be the traffic cop between the two. So in a typical MVC application the controller is very light weight This can happen because we are passing objects around, and one of those objects may be a view model that knows how to validate the data returned from the view. We don't have that luxury in RPG.

Comment: ... So maybe the controller needs to be a bit heavier, and know how to validate the input coming from the view. It would be interesting to see what you come up with, and how you separate concerns;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troubleshoot QMHSNDPM:  Before calling QMHRMVPM' and after calling QMHSNDPM look at the messages for the interactive job (system request 3 then option 10 then f10 then f18) if you don't see your message something is wrong with the program sending the message.  If you do see the message press f1 with cursor on the message then press F9 to see where the message was delivered.

Probably you need a msgCallStack of 2 or 3 for your program or 4 or 5 if you want the message back at the command line.

I put in oldschool format to see the variable names.

```
call      'QMHSNDPM'                 
parm                    msgIdIN      
parm                    msgLoc       
parm                    msgRplDta    
parm                    msgRplDtaLen 
parm                    msgType      
parm                    msgQueue     
parm       3            msgCallStack 
parm                    msgKey       
parm                    msgErr
```

That should shoot the message up from a procedure in the model back to the view.

For MVC style program in rpg interactive you start with the view then call down to the model which shoots the message back up to the view.  Maybe you have a controller that calls the view.

Comment: This got me where I needed to be.  I appreciate all the help from everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Keeping track of the current stack level can be tricky.

Keep in mind that when you're inside of a procedure the stack level is increased by 1. So if your current stack level is 1 and you call a procedure, the stack level inside of the procedure is 2.

In my apps I declare a global variable that's initialized to 1. Upon entry to a procedure I add 1 to that variable and upon exiting I subtract 1. That variable is passed to the QMHSNDPM API.

As an aside, a call to a subroutine does not add 1 to the stack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok....so maybe if the initial program is the CL INITIAL, and that calls the program CNTRL, which passes the values to the VIEW, then the call stack would be 3?  Because the CL would have to count.....and since I only tried 0,1,and 2....I just didn't take the testing far enough?  I'm going to go do that now......

Comment: Nope...3 and 4 didn't work either.  But it was worth a shot!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> // The MSGQ parameter is from the PSDS *PROC
>   // I tried having this defined in the view where the DDS file
>   // is defined, and I have tried with it defined in the main CNTRL program

So on the program stack, each stack entry has a message queue. You are stating that the message queue that you are using to initialize your message subfile is comming from the `PSDS *PROC`. So you need to send your messages to the same stack entry. The way I do this is to populate StackEntry and PGMMSGQ with the same variable, and make the Stack Counter 0.

This is my procedure for sending a message to the message subfile (I keep it in a service program):

```
   // ----------------------------------------
   // SndDspfMsgText - sends an *INFO message to the
   //     message subfile in a display file.
   //
   // Parameters:
   //  StackEntry - The program call stack entry to which the message is sent.
   //               Usually the program name. This must be the same value that
   //               is placed in the SFLPGMQ variable in the message subfile
   //               control format.
   //  MsgText -    Text of the messqage to be sent.
   //  MsgTextLen - The length of the message text provided above.
   // ----------------------------------------
   dcl-proc SndDspfMsgText Export;
     dcl-pi *n;
       StkEnt      Char(10)  Const;
       MsgText     Char(512) Const Options(*VarSize);
       MsgTextLen  Int(10)   Const;
     end-pi;

     dcl-ds MsgFile       LikeDs(QualName_t) Inz(*LikeDs);
     dcl-ds ErrorCd       LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t) Inz(*LikeDs);

     dcl-s pmMsgId          Char(7)   Inz('CPF9898');
     dcl-s pmMsgText        Char(512) Inz('');
     dcl-s pmMsgTextLen     Int(10)   Inz(0);
     dcl-s pmMsgTyp         Char(10)  Inz('*INFO');
     dcl-s pmStkCnt         Int(10)   Inz(0);
     dcl-s pmMsgKey         Char(4)   Inz('');

     // if Message Data is provided,
     if MsgTextLen > 0;
       pmMsgTextLen = min(%size(MsgText): MsgTextLen);
       pmMsgText = %subst(MsgText: 1: pmMsgTextLen);
     endif;

     MsgFile.Name = 'QCPFMSG';
     qmhsndpm(pmMsgId: MsgFile: pmMsgText: pmMsgTextLen:
              pmMsgTyp: StkEnt: pmStkCnt: pmMsgKey:
              ErrorCd);
   end-proc;
```

Here are a couple templates you are going to need to fully understand the above procedure:

```
   // Standard Error Code Format
   dcl-ds ErrorCdType1_t   Qualified Template Inz;
     BytesProv             Int(10)   Inz(%size(ErrorCdType1_t));
     BytesAvail            Int(10);
     MsgId                 Char(7);
     Data                  Char(1024) Pos(17);
   end-ds;

   // Qualified Name
   dcl-s Name_t            Char(10) Template Inz('');
   dcl-ds QualName_t       Qualified Template Inz;
     Name                  Like(Name_t) Inz('');
     Lib                   Like(Name_t) Inz('*LIBL');
   end-ds;

   // Call Stack Qualifier - used by message handling APIs
   dcl-ds CallStackQual_t  Qualified Template Inz;
     Module                Like(Name_t) Inz('*NONE');
     Program               Like(Name_t) Inz('*NONE');
   end-ds;

   // Send Program Message
   dcl-pr qmhsndpm      ExtPgm('QMHSNDPM');
     MessageId              Char(7)    Const;
     MessageFile            LikeDs(QualName_t) Const;
     MessageDta             Char(512)  Const Options(*Varsize);
     MessageLen             Int(10)    Const;
     MessageType            Char(10)   Const;
     StackEntry             Char(4102) Const Options(*Varsize);
     StackCounter           Int(10)    Const;
     MessageKey             Char(4);
     Error                  LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t);
     StackEntryLen          Int(10)    Const Options(*NoPass);
     StackEntryQual         LikeDs(CallStackQual_t)
                                       Const Options(*NoPass);
     ScreenWaitTime         Int(10)    Const Options(*NoPass);
     StackEntryType         Char(10)   Const Options(*NoPass);
     Ccsid                  Int(10)    Const Options(*NoPass);
   end-pr;
```